# Unable to deserialize an object of gson arrays in Java

Tags: json, gson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object in Java but `gson.fromJson()` does not seem to work. It's giving `null` value after deserialization.

I have a json response like this:

```
{
    "master": [{
        "data": {
            "getStoreItem": {
                "gtin": "84",
                "storeId": "49",
                "locations": {
                    "salesfloor": [{
                        "aisle": "5",
                        "aisleDesc": "5"
                    }]
                },
                "pricing": {
                    "retailPrice": 11.28,
                    "hoRetailPrice": null
                },
                "basicInfo": {
                    "itemNumber": 87,
                    "departmentNumber": 1
                },
                "inventory": {
                    "onHandQuantity": 358,
                    "inTransitQuantity": 0
                },
                "restrictions": {
                    "isAssociateDiscountable": false
                },
                "itemAssociatedGtins": [{
                    "gtin": "847"
                }]
            }
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "getStoreItem": {
                "gtin": "97",
                "storeId": "4",
                "locations": {
                    "salesfloor": [{
                        "aisle": "1",
                        "aisleDesc": "1"
                    }]
                },
                "pricing": {
                    "retailPrice": 19.98,
                    "hoRetailPrice": null
                },
                "basicInfo": {
                    "itemNumber": 871,
                    "departmentNumber": 1
                },
                "inventory": {
                    "onHandQuantity": 56,
                    "inTransitQuantity": 0
                },
                "restrictions": {
                    "isAssociateDiscountable": false
                },
                "itemAssociatedGtins": [{
                    "gtin": "9754610200"
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I have a `Master.java` class like this-

```
import java.util.List;

public class Master {

    List<Data> data;

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public static class Data {

        private GetStoreItem getStoreItem;
            public GetStoreItem getGetStoreItem() {
                return getStoreItem;
            }

            public void setGetStoreItem(GetStoreItem getStoreItem) {
                this.getStoreItem = getStoreItem;
            }

            public static class GetStoreItem {

                private String gtin;
                private String storeId;

                public String getGtin() {
                    return gtin;
                }

                public void setGtin(String gtin) {
                    this.gtin = gtin;
                }

                public String getStoreId() {
                    return storeId;
                }

                public void setStoreId(String storeId) {
                    this.storeId = storeId;
                }

            }
    }
}
```

When I'm doing:

```
Master m = gson.fromJson(json, Master.class);
```

`m` contains:

```
data: null
```

Unable to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you could try escaping your json string? I tested it to see what would happen but it appears Gson is unusable in an online IDE, however it did get rid of the `unclosed string literal` errors.

Comment: @Still_learning I'm not hardcoding the json. I'm getting the response from an external service. :)

Comment: @Still_learning I tried to hard code the json like this-
```"{\"master\": [{\"getStoreItem\": {\"gtin\": \"84\",\"storeId\": \"49\"}}]}"``` 
Still getting the same problem.
Maybe the problem could be the nested objects?

Comment: I meant escaping the json with line breaks like this: `"{\n\"Main\": [{\n \"data\": {\n\"getStoreItem\":{\\"gtin\": \"84\", ...` I did it [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html)

Comment: @Still_learning  It's working now. Had to modify the class a bit. Thanks for looking into it. :)

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance

Answer (score 0):

Your top-level class should have a field `master` of type `List` since in your JSON, `master` is the key in a key-value pair in the top-level JSON object and its value is a JSON array.

Moreover, the `data` field should be of type `Data` instead of `List` of `Data` since in your JSON, the values corresponding to the `data` keys are JSON objects.

```java
class StoreData {
    private List<StoreItem> master;

    static class StoreItem {
        private Data data;
    }

    static class Data {
        @SerializedName("getStoreItem")
        private GeneralData generalData;
    }

    static class GeneralData {
        private String gtin, storeId;
    }
}
```

```java
StoreData storeData = new Gson().fromJson(json, StoreData.class);
```

---

Some other notes:

- There is no reason here to create a nested class in another nested class (e.g., in your example you could make `GetStoreItem` a nested class of `Master`, instead of a nested class of `Data`).
- You can use [`@SerializedName`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) if your JSON does not match Java naming conventions (e.g., in your example `GetStoreItem` breaks conventions).